# Abstract Class to act as List Manager (List containing Lists) to reduce boilerplate code?

Tags: c#, list

Lets say I have the Person Class that has two lists (Email and PhoneDetails) and some people have more than one of each.

PhoneDetails has variables like: Number, Provider, PlanName... And Email is similar.

```
public class Person
{
    private String _FirstName;
    private String _LastName;
    private DateTime? _DateOfBirth = null;
    private List<Email> _Email = new List<Email>( );
    private List<PhoneDetails> _PhoneDet = new List<PhoneDetails>( );
}
```

Instead of writing the add, find, insert... for each one, I'm trying to think of a way to create a List Manager Abstract Class (or something) so I don't have to make all that boilerplate code, but can still manage the lists in a semi-controlled way (like permissions within the Person class)?

I'm sure that `List<List<object>> ListMgr = new List<List<object>>();` is a start, but it is just too daunting for me to figure out with my current skill level.

I know this is WAY beyond me, as I'm getting started, but I couldn't find anything like this anywhere and, because I use a lot of lists, thought I'd put it out here. Just not sure if Public is the best way to go...

Thank you.

Comment: It's not clear to me what boilerplate code you think is going to be eliminated by this list manager, nor how it will actually be used in practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you go about doing it like this

```
public class ListManager<A, B, C, D> : Tuple<List<A>, List<B>, List<C>, List<D>>
{}
```

this surely is a Strongly typed way but you will have to know the total Lists and their types before you start